# ¿Cómo lograr que input file permanezca intacto?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un formulario para actualizar perfiles en mi página, asimismo, incluye un campo "input type=file" para subir avatars, el cual funciona a la perfección, sin problemas, guardando la imagen en la carpeta especificada, el nombre de la imagen en la base de datos y los datos del perfil, igual, en la base de datos. Todo en un mismo formulario.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, ¿cómo logro que cada vez que se actualice el formulario (digamos que actualizan su nombre), no me borre el nombre del avatar almacenado en la base de datos si el campo "input type=file" del avatar está en blanco, o sea, no examinaron ni escogieron imagen?, y, de ser posible, sólo se actualice cuando se seleccione una imagen.

Un ejemplo más claro lo podrán encontrar en el sistema phpBB, el cual, al actualizar el perfil no borra los datos del avatar en la base de datos, si no se seleccionó una imagen.

Comment: Será algo así lo que quieres? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256119/php-mysql-conditional-update-query

Comment: pudiste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Para que permanezca intacto solo lo mandas a actualizar cuando tenga datos:

```
//en el javascript
if($('#file-input').val()){
    var file = $('#file-input').val()
    $.ajax({
        //envias el file
    })
}else{
    $.ajax({
        //no envias el file
    })
}
```

Comment: una disculpa la verdad no e usado ajax me podrias explicar como mandar el valor de la variable por favor

Comment: $.ajax({type: "POST",
                url: "urlservicio",
                data: {
                    datos:datos
                }
            }).done(function(data){console.log(data)})

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer la verificación antes de actualizar en la base de datos, es decir, en la ruta. Si la variable del archivo trae algo diferente a vacío, actualizas todo, sino, envías otro query en donde no se actualice el campo de la imagen.

```
//por ejemplo en node con JavaScript sería algo así
...
If ( file != ' ' ) {
    Query = "update TABLE set img=file, campo= valor;"
} else {
    Query = "update TABLE set campo=valor;"
}
//Ejecutas el query
```